# Upstart - stop: Unknown instance:

Tags: python, upstart

I'm trying to do a simple upstart script, I't seems to start, I don't see an error. Says it started running on 5975. But when I `ps ax | grep test` I see 11 instances.
When I try to `sudo stop test` I get `stop: Unknown instance:`

My example is bare bones, not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but obviously something isn't right.

**/etc/init/test.conf:**

```
description "test script"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn

chdir /var/www/html
exec nohup python test.py > test.out &
```

**test.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
while 1:
    print 'hello'
    time.sleep(60)
```

**Start**

```
ubuntu@1234:$ sudo start test
test start/running, process 5975

ps ax | grep test
5967 ?        S      0:00 python test.py
5970 ?        S      0:00 python test.py
5973 ?        S      0:00 python test.py
5976 ?        S      0:00 python test.py
5979 ?        S      0:00 python test.py
5982 ?        S      0:00 python test.py
5985 ?        S      0:00 python test.py
5988 ?        S      0:00 python test.py
5991 ?        S      0:00 python test.py
5994 ?        S      0:00 python test.py
5997 ?        S      0:00 python test.py
```

**Stop**

```
ubuntu@1234:$ sudo stop test
stop: Unknown instance: 


ps ax | grep test

5967 ?        S      0:00 python test.py
5970 ?        S      0:00 python test.py
5973 ?        S      0:00 python test.py
5976 ?        S      0:00 python test.py
5979 ?        S      0:00 python test.py
5982 ?        S      0:00 python test.py
5985 ?        S      0:00 python test.py
5988 ?        S      0:00 python test.py
5991 ?        S      0:00 python test.py
5994 ?        S      0:00 python test.py
5997 ?        S      0:00 python test.py
```

Comment: have you already tried this - stop on runlevel [!2345] ?

Comment: yes, I have tried that

Comment: This was answered here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152288

Answer (score -3):

the name instance is test.py, not test only

the command is sudo stop test.py

Comment: sudo stop test.py results in stop: Unknown job: test.py

Comment: try with `pkill -9 -f test.py`